# How can I get a value based on two other columns when one column value is ambigous in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, reference

I want to assign a variable depending on two column values. The input table `df_input` looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df_input = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "entity": [
            "Table_A",
            "Table_A",
            "Table_A",
            "Table_B",
            "Table_B",
            "Table_C",
        ],
        "field": [
            "Column 1",
            "Column 2",
            "Column 3",
            "Column 1",
            "Column 2",
            "Column 1",
        ],
        "type": ["new",
            "new",
            "new",
            "old",
            "new",
            "old",],
    }
)

Table_A = pd.DataFrame( 
                        {
                        "Column 1": [123],
                        "Column 2": ["XYZ"],
                        "Column 3": [True],
        }
)
```

This is how the Data looks like.

[image]

My goal is to determine the `type`, because certain functions are triggered depending on this value. But that is outside the scope for this question. My problem right now is that I want the `type` based on the `entity` and the `field`. So I tried this piece of code:

```
for field in df_input.field:
    print(f"{field=}")
    if field == Table_A.columns:
        type_variable = df_input.iloc[field]['type']
        print(f"{type=}")
```

In this case `Table_A` is a table which will be transformed based on the type value. But it is out of scope for this question.  All I receive is this error:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

```
Output:
new
new
new
old
new
old
```

I know why this error occurs. Right now I am not able to solve this issue. I would like to achieve that the `type_variable` will be output, depending on the `table` and the `column` so I can move on with this variable in the next function. Can anybody help me with that issue?

Comment: It looks like `df_object` contains the columns `Column 1`, `Column 2` and `Column 3`. The value `Column 1` occurs 3 times in `df_input.Field`, with corresponding `type` values of `new`, `old` and `old`. Which of these (`new` or `old`) do you want identify in your code?

Comment: Hey @constantstranger, the term `df_input` was unlucky. I changed it to `Table_A`. I want get the `type` value of the row because afterwards the column of the row will be transformed according to the type.

Comment: It seems as though you probably only want to examine the rows in `df_input` with `entity` equal to `Table A`, but it's not clear from your question. Can you try to update your question to clarify what output you are hoping for?

Comment: I would like to achieve that the type will be output, depending on the table and the column so I can move on with this variable in the next function.

Comment: @constantstranger added a few more details and the expected outcome. Sorry for some missleading informations

Comment: If the second dataframe is named `Table_A`, does this imply that only input rows with `entity` == 'Table A' are relevant? If so, why does your sample output show all rows (including those with `entity` of 'Table B' and 'Table C')?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
    if field == df_test.columns:
```

The question is [unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but perhaps you wanted `in`:

```
    if field in df_test.columns:
```

---

You might be better off mapping with just a python `dict`,
rather than `df_test`.

Comment: `df_test `is perhaps the wrong name(changed it to `df_object`).  Depending on `df_object` and its columns the `type ` has to be determined.